# Theorems on instability of classical systems of charged particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, stability

Classically, a hydrogen atom should not be stable, since it should radiate away all its energy. I remember hearing from my favorite freshman physics prof ca. 1983 about a general theorem to the effect that all classical systems of charged particles were unstable, and I went so far as to contact him in 2009 and ask him if he remembered anything about it, but he didn't. There is something called [Earnshaw's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem) that says that *static* equilibrium is impossible.

It certainly seems plausible that something similar holds for dynamical equilibrium, in some sense that I don't know how to define properly, much less prove rigorously. Intuitively, I would expect that any classical system of $m$ charged particles should end up having no "interesting structure," in the sense that the final state will consist of radiation plus $n \le m$ zero-size clusters whose charges $q_1,\ldots q_n$ all have the same sign (some possibly being zero); asymptotically, they all end up diverging radially from some central point.

Does anyone know of any formal proof along these lines?

Are there counterexamples, although possibly ones with initial conditions corresponding to zero volume in phase space?

How would one go about stating the initial conditions on the radiation fields?

Comment: @Ben Crowell The paper [can be found here](http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~rajeev/phy246/lieb.pdf).

Comment: @mmc: Thanks! It's completely quantum-mechanical, though.

Comment: @Ben Crowell Yes. I searched for classical analyses of this problem without success. With respect to your suggestion, I agree that it seems very plausible. But the "Off to Infinity in Finite Time" paper shook my confidence in intuition ;-)

Comment: @mmc: Exactly -- that's what started me thinking about this again. It seems like it's hard to be sure that there aren't exotic counterexamples. If the number of particles is allowed to be infinite, then I'm pretty sure there are counterexamples, and similarly if you're in a topologically nontrivial space.

Comment: Well the system can't be periodic, since some of the moments of the charge distribution would have to change, and that would radiate away energy. And it can't approach a periodic limit by that logic neither. So the options for long time behavior seem to be: i) collision or singularity in finite time (you seem to want to treat collisions as just two particles sticking together purely inelastically but that's its own deal) ii) Particles flying off to infinity (not sure why you want them to all have the same sign, doesnt seem necessary if you have enough energy) iii) the system loses energy

Comment: -cont- continuously without bound, but doesn't end up at i) or ii). Possibility iii) is interesting - it doesn't seem likely but I think we all agree that we have no intuition on these topics.

Comment: @BebopButUnsteady: Interesting thoughts, thanks! But IMO there is a significant gap in the step where you say that periodicity implies radiation. Given any charge distribution with, say, an electric dipole moment $d(t)$, I can always superimpose an oscillating dipole with $-d(t)$, so that the dipole radiation vanishes. Going on in this way, I don't see why I can't go on and cancel out the M1, E2, M2, ... modes all the way to infinitely high multipolarities. The question is whether these systems would obey the eqns of motion.

Comment: @BebopButUnsteady: Now that I think about it a little more, it's not obvious that you can even *make* a pointlike oscillating dipole with a desired frequency. I was naively imagining gluing a + and a - to opposite ends of a popsicle stick and spinning the stick end over end. But the problem is purely about interacting point charges. If you could make stable, rigid bodies like popsicle sticks, then you'd already have a trivial counterexample to the whole conjecture.

Comment: @Ben Crowell Can the proof not be iterative? Take two charges, there is no stable system because they will radiate  by the acceleration in the field of each other . Add a third charge while the two are falling in each other (or diverging), and treat the field of the two as one, the third one will also accelerate and depending on the charge balance will either fly away or fall in; etc.

Comment: Tangentially related: You maybe interested in the various [non-radiation conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonradiation_condition) for classical particles.

Comment: @Willie Wong Seems to me that the article you link answers the question in the negative. There cannot be a general theorem that says no stable dynamic  charge systems exist.

Comment: @Willie Wong: The material about non-radiation conditions is very interesting -- thanks! anna v: But I don't think it does what you're saying. If I'm understanding correctly (the WP refs are all paywalled), it's saying that a particle or particles driven by an external force may not radiate. That's different than saying that a dynamical system exists that doesn't radiate.

Comment: @Ben Crowell: Your procedure would work, but it would involve an infinite number of particles, whereas your question asked for a finite number of particles. I believe that there is no non-trivial motion of a finite number particles that doesn't change one of the moments, but I will admit I don't have a proof off the top of my head. By 'oscillating', I meant only 'periodic' - the naive way to have two charges move periodically is to set them in mutual orbit. But of course this is not stable, which is the whole point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy answer to your question but as for some possible leads and maybe a setup of the problem:

I'd try to write down the Hamiltonian for your configuration of particles.  (e.g chapter two in this fella's [thesis](https://physics.byu.edu/docs/thesis/185) in section 2.3 eq. 2.28 shows the Hamiltonian for two charged classical particles using center of mass coordinates.  You have n charged particles but the generalization to n is pretty straight-forward and contained in most undergrad books on mechanics.)

Then from there you want to proceed in your analysis as you would with the classical N-body problem as outlined in something like [Meyer and Hall](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/038797637X) Chapter 1.  Specifically look at things like Ch. 1, Sec. 4 on 'Equilibria for the Restricted 3-body problem' and techniques for finding critical points of modified potentials.

I'm willing to bet that for certain initial conditions (perhaps as an initial condition all particles are contained in the same plane) you'll be able to make a statement about the final configuration in a limiting case.  For the more general setup --  that's just GOTTA be an open problem.  I'd be really surprised if that was actually known at this point in time.

Regarding the question "How would one go about stating the initial conditions on the radiation fields?".. I'm not sure how to interpret a radiation field in a classical unless you push off into derivations that you find in plasma physics.  For a Hamiltonian setup tho [this](http://www.springerlink.com/content/x2774mtn06634563/) paper looks promising..  Truth is the more I think on it the more I think you might find an answer to your question in L&L's [Physical Kinetics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0750626356).  Chapter IV on instabilities might have something to say on this.

Anyways.. good luck.

Comment: Nice ideas, thanks! I don't think Adams' thesis helps, however, because he explicitly assumes no radiation (p. 10) -- which in my case is what I want to prove. Amazon doesn't let me view very much of Meyer and Hall's ch. 1, but from what I can see, it looks like they're talking about the Newtonian gravitational n-body problem, for which radiation is not an issue.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also not able to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.